# Authentication via API of a big project

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, authentication, architecture

There is a project and the database that contains the table "Users" with their login names and passwords.
The main project is Web, so there is used Forms authentication and it's fine.
However, the project provides some API so that other developers could develop their own software (for any platform: web, windows, iphone, android, etc) implementing more or less the same functionality that provides main web project.
However, the API must be accessible ONLY if the user successfully passed authentication.
So I was thinking about how to implement this functionality.

Option #1:
The API contains a method where the user could send their username/password and get some temperary token (what means I have to keep this token somewhere on the server and it's also the question: how long?) and then I could accept the other API calls if the user's token matches the one I keep somewhere on the server.
Sounds nasty.

Option #2:
All the API methods must also have additional fields: username/password.
Sounds nasty too.

Please advise what would be the proper option?

Answer (score 0):

Go with option #1. I would create a table in your database called `ApiKey` or something. I would have a foreign key to the user id and you can have an optional expiration field and/or maximum request limit. Create an API that authenticates a user, then creates a unique API Key, then send this key to the user. The user can use this API key to access the rest of your API.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to to as far as issuing tokens, look into supporting [OAuth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth).  It, there are even lots of nice packages that can handle a lot of this for you, making token management/authentication pretty seamless.

Also, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3997172/oauth-2-0-service-provider-net-libraries).  Don't write your own auth framework unless you absolutely have to.  Many people have already done this for you.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said before use option #1 with asp.net OWIN Middleware. You don't have to store the token at the server side, OWIN will issue a token and it has the responsibility to "decode" the token to find if it is valid. You don't need to write code to validate a token.

Sending username and password on every request? Never never never.

Read more about OWN and Katana: [OWIN and Katana](http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/owin-oauth-20-authorization-server)

A good article on securing Web API: [Secure WEB API](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/individual-accounts-in-web-api)